# Realtime sync between Oracle db(source) and Mongodb(destination)

Tags: mongodb, oracle, database-replication

Is it possible to have a real time sync between a heavy Oracle database and mongodb? Has any one tried this?

I saw a site - [Keep MongoDB and Oracle in sync](http://tebros.com/2011/09/keep-mongodb-and-oracle-in-sync-using-streams-advanced-queuing/)

Here they have mentioned having triggers on the oracle tables, my doubt is that will this slow the applications already running on the Oracle database. Will this replication cause the applications to slow down or bring down the oracle database's performance?

Answer (score 1):

The right solution would involve Change Data Capture from Oracle. This does not require triggers on oracle and thus won't effect performance. There are several tools you can use such as Striim and Attunity. Striim supports change data capture from Oracle and writing to MongoDB.

https://striim.com

https://attunity.com